# Dynamic Display in Base HTML using DJango

Tags: html, django

I am new to DJango and i am creating a Website. I have created a base HTML page with a NAV bar which will be used across all pages. I want to display the message "Welcome 'username'"  as the first line across all pages.

I had written the following code in views.py

```
def getusername(request):
uname=request.getusername()
return render(request,'main.html',{'uname':uname})
```

in the main.html after defining the title and nave bar, i have the following html code

```
<span class="label label-default">Welcome{{uname}}</span>
```

When i run this code, I am able to view the NavBar in all pages tat extends the base page(main.html)

but the welcome message does not fetch the username.

I have configured the following in urls.py

```
path("", views.getusername,name='getusername')
```

Note: Even when i hardcode a string to be returned from views.py, the string is not displayed as part of the welcome message

Answer (score 0):

In every template you have access to *user* object.
You can check if user is authenticated:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Welcome, {{ user.username }}
{% else %}
    # show register or(and) login button
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Did a small check today, without any changes to the above code, i viewed the base HTML(main,html in my case). I could see the username with which i logged in displayed. @qwanysh , I added the code snippet you had suggested in my base HTML and it always enters the else part of the code. the value for user.username is an empty string